# nodejs + sequelize (MariaDB) model.count() returning NaN

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

When I am using sequelize with postgres. Its working fine but when I am using mariaDB strange issue happening.

```
let emailExists = await models.user.count({
    where: {
      id,
      email,
      status: true,
    },
  });
```

from log i can see its generating

```
SELECT count(*) AS `_0` 
FROM `users` AS `user` 
WHERE `user`.`id` = 1 
AND `user`.`email` = 'user@example.com' 
AND `user`.`status` = true;
```

But `console.log(emailExists);` is `NaN`

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small issue i had `minifyAliases: true` added in connection. Just removing solved the issue. Hope it may help someone also from some silly mistakes.